# Response from browser is different from the response retrieved via a React app

Tags: reactjs, c++11, mongoose-web-server

I am trying to query my server (mongoose C++) from a react app by sending a get request $IP/query/. The response I get is different from the response I get if I write the same query in a web browser $IP/query/

Comment: Hey there. Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is hard to post an answer for because there is very little detail. Check out this guide to posting a good question. It will increase your odds of getting answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you should at least post how you do the requests and what the responses look like.